# How to detect EAR with ArCore android

Tags: android, arcore

So I am trying to put a earing on a person with ArCore. But the Face ArCore mask does not cover ears best i can do is at 172 but its still far away from the ear.

[image]

this is my code

```
private fun getRegionPose(region: FaceRegion): Vector3? {
        val buffer = augmentedFace?.meshVertices
        if (buffer != null) {
            return when (region) {
                FaceRegion.EAR ->
                    Vector3(
                        buffer.get(177 * 3),
                        buffer.get(177 * 3 + 1),
                        buffer.get(177 * 3 + 2)
                    )
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun onUpdate(frameTime: FrameTime?) {
        super.onUpdate(frameTime)
        augmentedFace?.let { face ->
            getRegionPose(FaceRegion.EAR)?.let {
                mustacheNode?.localPosition = Vector3(it.x, it.y - 0.035f, it.z + 0.015f)
                mustacheNode?.localScale = Vector3(0.07f, 0.07f, 0.07f)
            }
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me please is there a way for me to go outside the bonds of the face lnadmakrs?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of research i found this example and it was what lead me to my answer. So i leave the tutorial here hopefouly it can help some one.

https://www.kodeco.com/523-augmented-reality-in-android-with-google-s-face-api#toc-anchor-003